# Failed to load ApplicationContext for JUnit test of Spring

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm writing test class with `@ContextConfiguration`. But I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext` error.
File Structure

```
project
    *src/main
      java
         com.abc.controller
             abc.java
      resources
         sample-client.xml
         rest-client.xml
    *Test
      com.abc.client
         Client.java
```

Test class Client.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:/sample-client.xml"})
public class Client {
    @Resource(name = "facebookClient")
    FacebookService facebookService;

    @Test
    public void getBeans() {
        System.out.println(facebookService.getBeans(1L));
    }
}
```

Trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:319)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [file:/C:/Users/Vivek/Desktop/work/zessta/esocialbooks/branches/esocialbooks/esocialbooks-api-client/target/classes/sample-client.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.setFactoryBean(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:235)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.setFactoryBean(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder;
    at org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.AbstractFactoryBeanDefinitionParser.doParse(AbstractFactoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 36 more
```

sample-client.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
       http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:/rest-client.properties"
                                  ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
    <import resource="classpath*:/rest-client.xml"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.esocialbooks.api.service"/>

    <jaxrs:client id="facebookClient" address="http://localhost:8080/abc/facebook"
                  serviceClass="com.abc.api.service.FacebookService"
                  inheritHeaders="true">
        <jaxrs:headers>
            <entry key="Authorization" value="-1:oes8ghQs52Wiq0N"/>
        </jaxrs:headers>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="customResponseExceptionMapper"/>
        </jaxrs:providers>
        <jaxrs:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="timeoutConfigInterceptor"/>
        </jaxrs:outInterceptors>
    </jaxrs:client>

</beans>
```

rest-client.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.commons.apiprovider" />

    <bean id="timeoutConfigInterceptor" class="com.abc.commons.apiprovider.interceptors.TimeoutConfigInterceptor">
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="100000" />
        <property name="receiveTimeout" value="100000" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: What versions of the Spring libraries are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Context initialization failed after updating Spring Version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405498/context-initialization-failed-after-updating-spring-version)

Comment: Your version of cxf is not compatible with spring 4.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a jar conflict or a case of using an older version of the code with a newer version of Spring libraries.

[Spring 3.0 API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/) for the method `setFactoryBean` actually specifies that it is deprecated.

If you are using [Spring 4.0](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/) then this method doesnt exist, hence the `NoSuchMethodError`.

the `setFactoryBean` is deprecated and doesnt show up in the API for Spring 4.0. You would have to refactor your code to accomodate this.

Comment: What changes should I make to get rid of this issue

Comment: post your xml config in the question, then lets see.

Comment: I made necessary changes to question

Comment: Please post the contents of `rest-client.xml`. Also, since you are using the component scan i believe you are explicitly calling the `BeanDefinitionBuilder.setFactoryBean` in one of your classes which is handcrafting the app context.

Comment: I have added rest-client.xml

Comment: you will have to modify the way you are handcrafting the bean definitions to be Spring 4.0 compliant. You will have to post the class which is responsible for that as well as mentioned in my previous comment