# Context initialization failed after updating Spring Version

Tags: java, spring, cxf, nosuchmethoderror, spring-4

I've recently updated my Spring version from 3.2.4.RELEASE to 4.0.7.RELEASE
and since then I'm getting this error while loading context.

Please let me know if I'll have to make any changes to context xml after updating spring version.

Here is the **avengers-flow-context.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:int-jmx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx/spring-integration-jmx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-1.5.xsd">

    <beans:import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/integration/avengers-properties-context.xml" />
    <beans:import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/integration/avengers-common-context.xml" />
    <beans:import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/integration/avengers-jms-context.xml" /> 
    <beans:import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/integration/avengers-jmx-context.xml" />
    <beans:import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/integration/avengers-saf-config.xml" /> 
    <beans:import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/integration/avengers-saf-jms-config.xml" /> 
    <beans:import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/integration/avengers-exception-context.xml" />
    <beans:import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/integration/avengers-common-context.xml" /> 
    <beans:import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/integration/avengers-hulc-flow-context.xml" />
    <beans:import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/integration/cxf-servlet-context.xml" />
```

Here is **avengers-hulc-flow-context.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd 
                        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

    <!-- xml files in dependency jar -->
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
    <!-- End of dependent jar xml files -->

    <!-- hulc service rest container -->
    <jaxrs:client id="AlertRestService" 
            address="${application.ping.consumer.url}"
            serviceClass="com.marvel.avengers..hulc.client.hulcWebService">
            <jaxrs:headers>             
                <entry key="Accept" value="application/json"/>         
                <entry key="Type" value="application/json"/>         
            </jaxrs:headers>
            <jaxrs:providers>        
                <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>        
            </jaxrs:providers>
            <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
                <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
            </jaxrs:inInterceptors>         
            <jaxrs:outInterceptors>
                <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
            </jaxrs:outInterceptors>            
    </jaxrs:client>

    <!-- hulc service rest container -->
    <jaxrs:client id="hulcLifecycleRestService" 
            address="${{application.ping.hulc.lifecycle.consumer.url}"
            serviceClass="com.marvel.avengers..hulc.client.lc.LifecycleWebService">
            <jaxrs:headers>             
                <entry key="Accept" value="application/json"/>         
                <entry key="Type" value="application/json"/>         
            </jaxrs:headers>
            <jaxrs:providers>        
                <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>        
            </jaxrs:providers>
            <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
                <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
            </jaxrs:inInterceptors>         
            <jaxrs:outInterceptors>
                <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
            </jaxrs:outInterceptors>            
    </jaxrs:client>

</beans>
```

Here is stack-trace:

```
    ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:/META-INF/spring/integration/avengers-hulc-flow-context.xml]
Offending resource: URL [file:/xyz/abc/.../WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/integration/avengers-flow-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [file:/xyz/abc/.../WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/integration/avengers-hulc-flow-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.setFactoryBean(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:248)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [file:/xyz/abc/.../WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/integration/avengers-hulc-flow-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.setFactoryBean(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:242)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.setFactoryBean(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder;
        at org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.AbstractFactoryBeanDefinitionParser.doParse(AbstractFactoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:136)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:60)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
        ... 37 more
 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] [support.XmlWebApplicationContext] Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Dec 10 08:30]; root of context hierarchy
 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1] [support.XmlWebApplicationContext] Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Dec 10 08:30]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:346)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:882)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:843)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5033)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5685)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1] [support.XmlWebApplicationContext] Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Dec 10 08:30]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:890)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:843)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5033)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5685)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.marvel.avengers</groupId>
  <artifactId>ultron-web-alert-rt</artifactId>
  <version>2015.02.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>ultron-web-alert-rt</name>

    <properties>    
        <activemq.version>5.8.0</activemq.version>  
        <spring.version>4.0.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.integration.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <xmlbeans.version>2.6.0</xmlbeans.version>
        <commons.codec.version>20041127.091804</commons.codec.version>
        <ibm-mq.version>7.1.0.2</ibm-mq.version>
        <servlet.version>3.0.1</servlet.version>
        <cassandra.version>2.0.8</cassandra.version>
        <datastax.version>2.0.5</datastax.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
        <jasypt-spring.version>1.9.0</jasypt-spring.version>
        <flume.version>1.4.0</flume.version>
        <drools.version>6.0.1.Final</drools.version>
        <cxf.version>2.7.8</cxf.version>    
        <jaxws.version>2.2.9</jaxws.version>    
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>                   
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbpm-bpmn2</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>                       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq</artifactId>
            <version>${ibm-mq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.jmqi</artifactId>
            <version>${ibm-mq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mqjms</artifactId>
            <version>${ibm-mq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>disthub2.dhbcore</artifactId>
            <version>${ibm-mq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
          <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
          <version>${activemq.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
          <artifactId>connector</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>        
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-jmx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-stream</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>               
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>${jasypt-spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring31</artifactId>
            <version>${jasypt-spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
            <version>${cassandra.version}</version> 
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>            
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>            
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>           
                </exclusion>    
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cassandra.deps</groupId>
                    <artifactId>avro</artifactId>           
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty</artifactId>          
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>          
                </exclusion>                 
            </exclusions>                   
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxws.version}</version>
        </dependency>                                       
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>
                        WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.mq-7.1.0.2.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.mq.jmqi-7.1.0.2.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.mqjms-7.1.0.2.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/disthub2.dhbcore-7.1.0.2.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/javax.jms-7.1.0.2.jar
                    </packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency> 
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId> 
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId> 
                <version>14.0.1</version> 
            </dependency>
            <dependency> 
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId> 
                <artifactId>netty</artifactId> 
                <version>3.9.0.Final</version> 
            </dependency>       
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>     
</project>
```

Comment: Incompatible versions of jar dependencies most likely.

Comment: Let us see your pom.xml if you are using maven or list of jars

Comment: @KarthikPrasad: I've added POM here, please take a look.

Comment: Interesting names by the way!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087355/failed-to-load-applicationcontext-for-junit-test-of-spring

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade CXF past version 2.7.8.  CXF 3.X was the first version to work with (and be tested against) Spring 4.

If you look at the manifest (META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) in the Apache CXF JAR you'll see that it supports up to, but not including Spring 4.0.  The following line is taken from latest 2.7 release:

```
org.springframework.beans;resolution:=optional;version="[2.5,4)"
```

Comment: I should have updated the `POM.xml`
I've updated the cxf version already, I did see some new errors.

Let me update the above logs and POM.xml and the context.xml(for jaxrs)

Comment: Then there is another error.  To get past this issue in AbstractFactoryBeanDefinitionParser you need to update to 3.0 where it correctly uses a raw bean definition.  This CXF and Spring combination won't work.

Comment: After I updated the CXF version to 3.0.3 and fixed the xsd's in the `avengers-hulc-flow-context.xml` it worked.
thanks @Jeff.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `mvn dependency:tree`
2. Find out (grep) all spring versions in the tree.
   90% that you'll find incompatible versions used by other dependecies.
3. Update those dependecies or exclude spring in them

Comment: I've tried running `mvn dependency:tree` But that won't help here.
Here the issue is with the `BeanDefinitionBuilder.setFactoryBean` method, its been removed in Spring 4.
setFactoryBean is being explicitly called from `avengers-hulc-flow-context.xml`
need to see how I can fix this.

Comment: Well, both are true. There's a dependency issue which manifests in the fact that cxf is calling setFactoryBean.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Folder Structure is wrong . META-INF must be parellel to **WEB-INF** as **META-INF** contains the **META** Data for the we application. It should not be present after **classes** folder

Comment: Actually the folder structure is correct, I've changed the file names and the class path.

Answer (score 0):

(As stated by original poster in a comment)

The `BeanDefinitionBuilder.setFactoryBean` method has been removed in Spring 4. 
`setFactoryBean` is being explicitly called from `avengers-hulc-flow-context.xml`

In the stacktrace this shows as

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.setFactoryBean(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
```

The offending call is made by cxf, so the version of cxf you're using is not compatible with spring 4. (Like Jeff says.)

```
org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.AbstractFactoryBeanDefinitionParser.doParse(AbstractFactoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:136)
```

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/30-migration-guide.html may be of use migrating to cxf 3.